# How to successfully transfer GCP projects from personal account to Cloud Identity-enabled GCP account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Currently I have a personal GCP account with various projects. But I want to have my projects associated with an organization, therefore I created a new Clound Identity-bound GCP account. Next I attempted to transfer GCP projects from my personal GCP account to the new Cloud Identity enabled GCP account, using the tool [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/org-onboarding/migration/request).

While I was able to successfully send a project migration request from the new Cloud Identity-backed GCP account to my personal GCP account, when I get to the "Review Migrate Screen -> Select Projects" dialog it shows no projects to be selected. Simply the text "No projects available for migration" is displayed.

[Review Migrate Request dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBeHG.png)

Having a hard time finding any documentation whatsoever that details what to do in this situation. Any feedback or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

-Mike

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I replicated your scenario, read the documentation but I had the same issue.

However, I was able to migrate a project, all I did was add my GCP personal account into Cloud Identity and grant the project creator role, then I switched to my GCP personal account and went to the [Manage Resources Page](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-resource-manager?_ga=2.265306377.-702463239.1545093911), clicked on the three little dots of the project I wanted to migrate, select migrate and I chose my organization.

Edit: After trying again, I found out that you need to wait at least 5 min so the projects to migrate can be displayed, of course that the documentation doesn't mention it, I suggest you to send a feedback so it can be improved.

Comment: Thanks kornshell93. If I understand you correctly, instead of migrating from one account to another (personal GCP account to a Cloud Identity account), instead you converted your GCP personal account (which had the projects to migrate) to a Cloud Identity account? And then initiated a transfer?

Comment: No, basically I added my gcp personal account as a member of my cloud identity organization and  granted the role project creator, then I switched to that personal account and went to the manage resources page and chose the project I wanted to migrate.

Comment: However as I mentioned in the edit section, it seems you need to wait around 5 min before accepting the migration request.